# How to change the Firefox icon?

Tags: firefox, launcher, icons

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. I am currently using Firefox which is present on the Unity panel (or launcher). The problem is that the icon is a question mark. I want to change it to the standard Firefox icon.

When i tried  `cat /user/share/applications/firefox.desktop |grep Icon`

It says `no such file or directory exists`.

When i tried `find /usr/share/icons -type f -iname '*firefox*'`

It gave:

```
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/48x48/apps/firefox.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/16x16/apps/firefox.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/firefox-icon.svg
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/24x24/apps/firefox.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/22x22/apps/firefox.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/32x32/apps/firefox.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/256x256/apps/firefox.png
```

I have tried to go to applications and follow the usual process but I could not find Firefox in applications. Please suggest some way.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop | grep Icon`

Comment: And the output of `find /usr/share/icons -type f -iname '*firefox*'`

Comment: have you tried reinstalling firefox? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox`

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy firefox`

Comment: and the output of `which firefox`

Comment: 1. You misspelled `/usr` directory. The file should be `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`
 2. Mine says `Icon=firefox`. If that says the same (and still gives question mark ), you better download firefox icon from somewhere, like google images, and just set it manually.  High contrast images you see up in the output of `find` are black-and-white iconds, non-standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you've done or how you have installed firefox as there is no standard desktop file. Maybe you have removed Firefox earlier. Therefore re-install `firefox`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox
```

Then, if still not the correct icon appears, remove the starter and add the starter again.

Answer (score 1):

I have find a way :

1) connect yourself as `root`

2) go to `/usr/share/applications`

3) search for `firefox`

4) go to properties and change the (missing for quantum) icon

5) Tell me if it's ok.

Comment: Hi Mc Lovin, and welcome to askUbuntu! Your post is not a new answer,  respectively the same content was already posted.

Comment: Where ?   I simply used a method that worked for me using the graphic tools.

Comment: You can find it in the comments.

Comment: @abu_bua A comment is not an answer. Maybe this could be a community wiki answer, or the comment's author should be asked to post an answer. Anyway, an answer should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I do know i am late to the part but this did not work bc of ```/user``` when it should be ```/usr```